# Accessing TargetDir of a project with WiX preprocessor $var syntax

Tags: visual-studio, wix, wix3, votive

I have just started using WiX for the first time.

I added a WiX Votive project to my existing C project.

To automatically select the correct source folder for the binaries add used the following:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Trapeze Capture For Objective" FileSource="$(var.CaptureForObjective.TargetDir)">
```

That results in the following error:

```
1>C:\code\CaptureForObjective\Installer\Product.wxs(10,0): error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.CaptureForObjective.TargetDir)'
```

.

The C project is called CaptureForObjective, and the WiX project is called Installer.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 16):

In order for the variables to become defined, you must right-click your wix project and add a project reference to your C project . See also this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx).

Comment: Oh, my god, I wasted so much time. This was it. I have visited every page about the "Undefined preprocessor variable" on the internet.